# DatePicker doesn't display on top of ChildWindow in Wp7

Tags: datepicker, childwindow

i have developed child window control it has datepicker option .When i click the datepicker it has opened the date picker screen behind the Childwindow control so i am unable to select the date .

How can i display the date screen on my Child Window control ?

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative way for this Query.

```
Event : datepicker1_ManipulationCompleted

this.close(); // this is close to strat the date manipulation

Event :datePicker1_ValueChanged

this.show() ;// Again i shows the my closed child window
```